# Is there a faster way of printing "yes" when a value is true?

Tags: java, if-statement, system.out

the method printDetails its prints out yes if the airCon field airCon is true,But I think this is not the perfect way of doing it, so is there any other way of doing it?

```
public class Auto
{
    private boolean airCon;
    public Auto() {}
    public void setAirCon(boolean airCon) {
        this.airCon = airCon;
    }

    public void printDetails() {
        String con;
        if(airCon) {
            con = "Yes";
        } else {
            con = "No";
        }
        System.out.println(con);    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try a ternary:

```
System.out.println(aircon ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Ternary expressions are great for assigning something to either one value or the other based on a condition, all in one line. You can nest them too:

```
bool isConditionTrue, areYouSure;
string answer = isConditionTrue ? areYouSure ? "Yes" : "No" : "No";
```

which is a little easier read with parenthesis:

```
string answer =  isConditionTrue ? (areYouSure ? "Yes" : "No") : "No";
```

so the **areYouSure** boolean gets read only if the **isConditionTrue** boolean is true.

Comment: Apparently, I type too slow, haha

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the ternary operator:

```
String con = airCon ? "yes" : "no";
```

Same effect, less code.

P.S. You can of course move the whole expression into the `println()` if all you need to do is print it.

Answer (score 3):

That's a perfectly fine way to do it, if you want to save lines though you can use a ternary statement

```
System.out.println(aircon ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems perfectly fine. The code is a little long, but that's not necessarily a bad thing.

You can use a handy Java trick to simplify it a lot:

```
public void printDetails()
{
    System.out.println(airCon ? "Yes" : "No");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use ternary operator.

```
String con=airCon?"yes":"no"
```

Comment: shouldnt it be con==airCon ??

Comment: no it should be =.u can code like this con=(airCon==true ? "yes": "no");

Comment: My bad.! it has to be assignment operator not equals to. :P

Comment: true i am assigning thevalue in con. :P

Answer (score 0):

You have it correct.  While your code is a bit verbose, it is best to go with what you understand.  You could use a conditional statement:

```
System.out.println((airCon) ? "Yes": "No")
```

This does the same thing.

However, I would define a utility method in case you want to use it in other areas of your app.

```
public static String getYesNo(boolean input) {
   return ((input) ? "Yes": "No");
}
```

Here it would be better to make the "Yes" and "No" strings public static final's so they act as constants.

Answer (score 0):

or you could use this, saves you an else:

```
public void printDetails()
{
String con = "No";
if(airCon)
{
    con = "Yes";
}
System.out.println(con);

}
```